# Haskell - flip arguments of a typeclass with two parameters

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have a multiparam typeclass which supplies a function that makes sense to have its arguments swapped:

```
class Swappable a b where
    swappable :: a -> b -> Bool
```

So if `a` and `b` form `Swappable a b`, then `b` and `a` should form `Swappable b a`. Writing a swapped instance for each normal instance would be a chore, so I naively wrote

```
instance Swappable a b => Swappable b a where
    swappable b a = swappable a b
```

Which doesn't compile with the following error:

```
    • Illegal instance declaration for ‘Swappable b a’
        (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
         where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
         and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
         Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Swappable b a’
   |
12 | instance Swappable a b => Swappable b a where
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now, I'm not really averse to turning on `FlexibleInstances`, but I don't understand why I need it in the first place. All type variables there appear once, and are all distinct. So why do I get this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
```

Means that your instance must be of the form

```
instance Swappable (T a1 .. an) (U b1 .. bn) where ...
```

where `T` and `U` are type constructors. Without that extension, you can not have only  single variables `a` and `b` without a constructor on top.

`FlexibleInstances` is harmless, anyway, and should arguably turned on by default. Maybe a future revision of the Haskell Report will include it.

I would be far more concerned by the overlapping, instead. `instance Swappable b a => Swappable a b` will overlap with any other instance. It will also require undecidable instances. I'm not sure about what you are trying to achieve is a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you can write the following:

```
{-# LANGAUGE UndecidableSuperClasses #-} -- 2
class Swappable b a => Swappable a b where -- 1
      swappable :: a -> b -> Bool
      swappable = flip swappable -- 3
```

(1) makes it so that, if you know that `a` and `b` are `Swappable`, then you also know that `b` and `a` are `Swappable`. That is,

```
swappable' :: Swappable a b => b -> a -> Bool
swappable' = swappable
```

compiles, even though the argument order seems "wrong", because the `Swappable a b` constraint itself implies `Swappable b a`, and it is that implementation that the `swappable` call chooses.

(2) makes GHC stop complaining about the recursive superclass on `Swappable`. This is a recent feature, introduced in GHC 8.0.1. Note that we don't need `FlexibleInstances` (though it's harmless) or `UndecidableInstances` (which is mostly OK) or `OverlappingInstances` (which sets the klaxons blaring). `UndecidableSuperClasses` probably falls in between the first two on the "danger" scale.

(3) is the default implementation of `swappable`. You can make that whatever you like. Usage of this class proceeds as follows:

```
instance Swappable Bool Int where
  swappable _ 0 = False
  swappable True n = n > 0
  swappable False n = n < 0
instance Swappable Int Bool where -- program does not compile if this is missing

instance Eq a => Swappable a a where swappable = (==)
```

The `Swappable Int Bool` class has, as superclass, `Swappable Bool Int`, so its `swappable` can be defined in terms of that superclass. `Swappable Bool Int` contains the logic. If one of the instances were missing, then the other instance's superclass constraint would be unfulfilled, so the program wouldn't compile. In the `Swappable a a` case, the instance is its own "superinstance". (It does require `FlexibleInstances`, but the reason is orthogonal to our purposes.)

These all work:

```
> swappable 5 5 -- defaulted to Integer, mind you
True
> swappable True (5 :: Int)
True
> swappable (5 :: Int) False
False
> swappable' (0 :: Int) True
False
```