# Making a commutative class?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have a couple of classes of the form

```
class R a b
```

For the purposes of examples we will use the following simplified class:

```
class R1 a b where
  q :: a -> b -> Bool
```

Which express some relationship between `a` and `b`.

This underlying relationship is commutative, meaning that

```
R1 a b => R1 b a
```

where

```
q a b = not (q b a)
```

So of course I would like to write an instance that expresses this so I don't have to write nearly every instance twice.

```
instance R1 a b => R1 b a where
  q a b = not (q b a)
```

This instance is incredibly problematic. Now if I make an instance for `R1` I suddenly have an infinite number of (identical) instances for `R1`.  The compiler of course then has no way of knowing which one I want.

Is there a way I can build classes so that I don't have to make two versions of nearly every instance?

Comment: I don't think there's a clean way out. The only option I can see is enabling overlapping instances (a GHC extension) and deal with the consequences. That will essentially make concrete instances like `instance R1 Int Bool` to have "higher priority" over the commutation one. Be careful to always keep all the relevant instances in scope (so that the wrong one isn't picked). This extension is not something I usually recommend, since you'll need to walk on thin ice when using that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Haskell - flip arguments of a typeclass with two parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221528/haskell-flip-arguments-of-a-typeclass-with-two-parameters)

Comment: @HTNW I feel this question sort of starts where that one left off.  Nothing there does anything to solve my problem even though their class is pretty much identical.  Of course I am not an expert on how SO handles duplicates, so this might still leave it a duplicate.

Comment: The specific difference is that here I want to avoid writing instances twice, that is my goal.  The other question seems to be more concerned with having their code compile properly and understanding the error.  There are of course ways to answer both questions at once but none of the answers there seem to do that.